# Qt QML SVG filters (e.g. feGaussianBlur) support in Qt5.12 and up

Tags: qt, svg, qml

Is there any change on the Qt QML SVG filters(like feGaussianBlur) support from version 5.12 and up?

I need to use SVGs in a QML application. But the SVGs have a lot of filtering in them. In Inkscape, browsers and other software the SVGs are rendered correctly (e.g. showing the blurs), but in Qt application they are not.

As I searched on internet, Qt QML has limited support for SVG filtering. But the links I read are pretty old. Some examples:

- https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69226-Why-they-use-png-images-icons-instead-svg-in-examples
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9081
- https://www.kdab.com/vectors-scalable-things/

I have a simple Image that has an SVG file as source:

```
  Image {
          x: 0
          y: 0
          height: 120
          width: 120
          sourceSize.height: 120
          sourceSize.width: 120
          source: "qrc:/images/example.svg"
  }
```

And the SVG code looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
<defs>
    <style type="text/css">
        .p {
            filter: url(#e);
        }
    </style>
    <filter id="e" x="0" y="0" width="83" height="83" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <feOffset dx="8" dy="8" input="SourceAlpha" />
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5.0" result="f" />
        <feComposite operator="in" in2="f" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
</defs>
<g transform="translate(10.5 10.5)">
    <g class="p" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -10.5, -10.5)">
        <circle class="a" cx="28" cy="28" r="28" transform="translate(10.5 10.5)" />
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Any news about the SVG filtering support?

Or am I missing something?

Is there any other approach?

Comment: Why not ask on the Qt site itself i.e. your first link?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Robert Longson. I have posted there as well and I will update this question if I get any solution there. Until now, I did not found anything relevant.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the rendering ?

Comment: As described in the [Rendering SVG Files](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html) Qt (right for v. 5.15) supports SVG [Tiny 1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12/) that was published at 22 December 2008 (and say nothing about filters). `filter` option is a part of [SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#FilterElement) that was published at 16 August 2011 so I think that QML doesn't support for this option.

Comment: @APianist, for example the blurs are not rendered.